spring-rabbitmq multicast aggregation response problem
I have a use case whereby I need to multicast a request message from a camel route to worker routes sitting in independent applications. So far I'm using spring-rabbitmq and I've been able to multicast the message, process the request in each worker and respond to the parent application. The aggregator route which listens on the responses from the workers (on response queues) is able to accomplish its task as needed. The issue arises when i need to send aggregated response back to this REST route
 rest().get("/orders/check-user-account").routeId("user-account")
            .consumes("application/json")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            .produces("application/json")
            .to("direct:request");

which I'm using to receive requests from users then send it to "direct:request" before multicasting.
Is it possible to have a response route that my rest().get(... will use to respond to the client? Or how can i respond to the client using the aggregated response.
My aggregator strategy
List<String> queues = msRabbitConfigs.getResponseQueues();
    List<String> exchanges = msRabbitConfigs.getExchange_response();

    IntStream.range(0, queues.size()).forEach(i -> {

        from("spring-rabbitmq:" + exchanges.get(i) + "?queues=" + queues.get(i) + "&exchangeType=direct&routingKey=" + exchanges.get(i))
                .process(exchange -> {

                    String correlationId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("correlationId", String.class);
                    String workerBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("correlationId", correlationId);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(workerBody);

                })
                .to("seda:aggregateResponses");
    });

    // Route to aggregate responses
    from("seda:aggregateResponses")
            .aggregate(header("correlationId"), new RabbitAggregation())
            .completionSize(msRabbitConfigs.getResponseQueues().size())
            .completionTimeout(5000)
            .log("Results ${body}");


As you have the message broker to decouple things, maybe the systems are not available at all, this is a highly asynchronous action. You should provide a callback url or something like that, which you can call after all the processing happened. You need to make sure, the callback url survive your aggregation strategy, for example in a header.
